# Script on play framework not applying

Tags: sql-server, playframework, evaluation

I trying to use ms sql server with play framework. I downloaded jar file "jtds-1.3.1.jar" with "jtds" driver. Put it in "lib" folder of my project.

Edited config file:
        db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
        db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TechElit"
        db.default.user=TechElit
        db.default.password="!23qweasd"

```
    ebean.default="models.*"
```

Edited build.scala file:

```
    val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    //Added this line
    "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2"
    )
```

When I trying to run my project I getting standard evaluation message:
"Database 'default' needs evolution!
An SQL script will be run on your database -"

Bun when I pressing button "Apply this script now!", page reload and I see this messsage again, no database tables doesn't creates.